# JavaScript - Babel - literal not recognized

Tags: javascript

Seems Babel REPL https://babeljs.io/repl/
does not recognize this expression.

`var x = 20n;`

Any ideas why? 
I thought these BigInt literals were introduced in ES6 and Babel
should recognize them and transform them to ES5 compliant code.

Am I missing something?

Comment: _“I thought these BigInt literals were introduced in ES6”_ — No, they [_will_ be introduced in ECMAScript _2020_](https://github.com/tc39/proposals/blob/master/finished-proposals.md). Babel [doesn’t appear to support them yet](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es2016plus/#test-BigInt). There is also no way to transpile BigInts to ES5 without some significant performance loss.

Comment: https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-bigint-objects 2020 spec

Comment: Oh, OK... Thanks.